# Php SQL Syntax error by a database alignment (?)!

Tags: php, sql, pdo, shopware

Sry if im just being blind, but this does make no sense, because I always did write it like this and I and see anything wrong with it. Besides I used multiple SQL solutions bit still errors in syntax...

My php code here:

```
$sql1 = " SELECT table1.file_name, table2.path
                FROM table1 AS t1
                LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2
                ON t1.file_name = t2.path
                WHERE t2.path IS NULL OR t1.file_name <> t2.file_name OR t1.file_name <> t2.path";

    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO table3 (file_name) VALUES(".$sql1.")";

    Shopware()->Db()->query($sql2);
```

My error message:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT table1.file_name, table2.path FROM (the first 2 letters of table1)' at line 1 in Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php on line 234
```

Comment: That is not how one writes an [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`INSERT..SELECT` statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) are written as:

```
INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM ...;
```

*Not* as `INSERT INTO ... VALUES (SELECT ... FROM ...);`.

Comment: yep... thx buddy!
I guess the error message confused me a bit to much ;)

Comment: Admittedly, MySQL's error messages *are* pretty bad. Just remember that when it says "check syntax near ...", it simply means it didn't expect to find "..." at that particular point, which means something *before* it is probably wrong.